# Where can I browse RFC and ISO datetime formats?

Tags: datetime, time, utc, web-standards

I'm looking to write a function to convert my server-side datetimes into my user interface datetimes, and I haven't decided on a format for either. Ideally, I'd like my function to take one standard datetime format, and return another standard datetime format.

Is there a cheat sheet, web site, or a spreadsheet that visually shows the difference between many standard date formats side by side? I'm looking for something like the ["localized notations" documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) for PHP's compound date and time formats, only more comprehensive.

Are there any standards that are designed for presentation to end users - something like "January 4th, 1983 6:34 PM"?

Answer (score 1):

Use and store dates in a simple, unambigous format like `ISO-8601`.

Rely on operating system support to convert these ISO dates into a nice localized display format. Otherwise you are just duplicating (*) the OS.

(*) : and probably "duplicating badly" because MS and Apple have far more experience and resources than you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Wikipedia article on [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)? I usually try to use one of those formats when outputting dates. Additionally, the link in that article to [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) has some examples. I'm not sure if these fit your side-by-side desire, but they're a start. You might find Wikipedia's [Date and time notation by country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_by_country) useful in that regard.

Comment: Yep - actually, those two very articles are the thing that made me answer the question. Both links go into detail explaining the actual difference between the standards - that's useless to me. What I need - and what most developers need, I'd argue - is a huge poster made by a graphic designer cataloging all the ways to express different kinds of dates in alphanumerics side by side, without having to wade through phrases like "Appendix A contains an attempt to translate the complete syntax of ISO 8601 into ABNF."